# rails 3: update_attributes doesnt update and responds with 422 HTML Status Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, best-in-place

I use Ruby 3.2.13, Best_in_place and Mongoid. When i want to update my mongodb record of a collection select, it doesnt work and responds with 422 HTML Status Code. Every other field updates correctly. The collection is made of another model.

This is my update definition:

```
def update
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
    respond_with @book
end
```

And here the best_in_place select snippet:

```
<%= best_in_place @book, :publisher_id, type: :select, collection: Publisher.all.order_by([:name]).map {|x| [x.id, x.name] } %>
```

Publisher: has_many :books, and Book: belongs_to publisher

Can anybody help me please? If you need additional information, i will post it. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was a validation, that prohibited me to update. Cause when i update this field, a saved file, that is saved in a directory with the name of the publisher, isn't accessible any more.